# Discussion Board reply subject for workflow

Tags: workflow, discussion-board, workflow-variable

I'm creating a workflow for a discussion board, that will create a new item in an announcements list. The idea is to have announcements such as

```
New Forum Post: 'This is a new post' was posted by me@myaddress.com
```

or

```
New Forum Reply: A reply to posted to 'This is a new post' by someoneelse@theiraddress.com
```

I've found the right lookups for the new post `Subject` and `Posted By`, but I can't figure out how to get the subject when a reply is created. I've tried lookups like `Discussion Subject`, `Discussion Title`, etc., but none seem to work.

Can anyone advise on the right lookups to use?
Any websites that list all the lookups and what values they may contain?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer - use a lookup for User Profiles:User Name, matching that username on the created account name.